# AWS organization "Re-register" organizational unit - boto3 or aws cli Command line equivalent needed

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/controltower/latest/userguide/importing-existing.html

> For example, if you see 4 of 5, it means that your OU has 5 accounts
> in total, and 4 of them enrolled successfully, but one account failed
> to enroll during the Register OU process. You can choose Re-Register
> OU to bring accounts into enrollment, after you make sure the accounts
> meet the enrollment prerequisites.

Now Re-register of OU can be done using web console. I am looking for doing the same using aws cli or boto3. But cannot find the correct commands.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/organizations.html

https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/organizations/index.html#cli-aws-organizations

Can any one please help me find the correct command either in boto3 or aws cli for "Re-register" Organizational unit (OU)?

Thanks

Comment: I dont have access to an AWS org at the moment but cant you not just test to move the account and have the from and to ou set to the same?
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/organizations/client/move_account.html

Comment: @ErikAsplund Thanks. So move_account is similar to Re-register OU?

Comment: What I get from Re-register OU it sounds like it just tries to re add the account to the OU. And this is what you will do by moving the account to the OU again.

Comment: @ErikAsplund After Moving an account to OU. If the account is not visible in OU, it is THEN you run Re-register. Correct? So move_account and Re-register and completely different isn't it? Thanks